# Default Entry in a Database

Tags: database, web-applications

**tl;dr** best way to set one instance of a model as the default one?

In a database, I want to have *one* default User. The way I'm currently doing this is by giving each user a Boolean `default` attribute, and making it false for every User but one. However, to change the default User I have to find the current default, set his `default` to false, and then set the new default. And hypothetically there could be more than one user with `default: true`, which could cause problems. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to have a separate relation (table) let's name it `default_user` that will hold only one row with a value of the current default user

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE default_user
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

This way if you need to fetch a default user you do

```sql
SELECT u.id, name
  FROM users u JOIN default_user d
    ON u.id = d.user_id
```

If you need to change the default user you just do an update

```sql
UPDATE default_user
  SET user_id = 3
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a5b95/2)** demo